# What is an ideal age gap for between parrot friends?

Tags: socializing, birds, parrots, age

I have a 9-month old Indian Ringneck parrot. I plan to get more parrots in the future (most likely smaller parrots). I am most likely to wait until he is 2 to get another parrot, but that is uncertain.

Is a Ringnecks' friendliness toward other parrots affected by how old they are when they are introduced? Would 2 years be too old or too young to introduce my Ringneck to a buddy?

Comment: I asked a friend who has an Alexandrine (& other parakeets) your question. She stated that 9 months was a good age to introduce another bird & that younger would be better.

Answer (score 4):

It's very hit or miss with parrots regardless of age, as babies they are more likely to get along however once they become adults it still has a chance to turn sour.

Some things to keep in mind when introducing new birds to the flock.

- Testing new birds for [Chlamydia](http://www.avianbiotech.com/diseases/chlamydia.htm) and [PBFD](http://www.avianbiotech.com/diseases/pbfd.htm), quarantine is a must until you get results.
- Have a separate cage for the new member.
- Birds that are planned to be housed together should be of similar size with a large enclosure.

### How to introduce

1. Once the new bird has been cleared for disease he/she can be placed at the opposite end of the same room. This allows the birds to see each other safely.
2. Every few days the cages can get closer together, watch each birds body language to determine if they are stressed, irritated, intrigued etc.
3. When introducing it should be on common ground and **NEVER** in/on either birds cage.
4. Never force an interaction and always supervise, if they choose to be close to each other in a friendly manner than great! Always have a towel on hand in case a fight breaks out, use the towel to create a wall between the two.
5. Reward friendly interactions with praise and treats.

In the end they may never get along so be prepared to house 2 birds separately, they can still live in harmony as long as they are not forced to live close to one another.

** **For a bird to truly be quarantined they cannot share the same air space as other birds.**